# How to define a property to be either Color or LinearGradient in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, user-interface, colors, swiftui, linear-gradients

I want to store a `backColor` property to be used for drawing. How can I make this property takes either Color or LinearGradient?

```swift
struct Card {
    let backColor: Color
}

let colorBackCard = Card(backColor: Color.red)
let gradientBackCard = Card(backColor: LinearGradient(...))
```

Last line of code showing: Cannot convert value of type 'LinearGradient' to expected argument type 'Color'.

How can I fix this property?

Thanks

--

I tried this:

```swift
enum ColorGradient {
    case color(Color)
    case gradient(LinearGradient)
}

struct Card {
    let backColor: ColorGradient
}

let colorBackCard = Card(backColor: ColorGradient.color(Color.red))
let gradientBackCard = Card(backColor: ColorGradient.gradient(LinearGradient(...)))
```

But when I use this property to draw in View, it reports:

Instance method 'background(_:alignment:)' requires that 'ColorGradient' conform to 'View'

--

I now use 2 separate variables Color? and LinearGradient?.

Comment: Use associated enums.

Comment: @CosmosMan thanks for the reply. I update the question to add associated enums like that. But I got error: Instance method 'background(_:alignment:)' requires that 'ColorGradient' conform to 'View'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use it directly in view then the following would be more appropriate

```
struct Card<Background: View> {
    let backColor: Background
}

// no changes in below
let colorBackCard = Card(backColor: Color.red)
let gradientBackCard = Card(backColor: LinearGradient(...))
```

Comment: i agree  :) this is a better way

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there initially!

The thing is, just conform `ColorGradient` to `View` like so:

```swift
enum ColorGradient: View {
    case color(Color)
    case gradient(LinearGradient)
    
    var body: some View {
        switch self {
        case let .color(view):
            view
        case let .gradient(view):
            view
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it like a view:

```swift
struct Card: View {
    let backColor: ColorGradient
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Card")
            .background(backColor)
    }
}
```